# react Browserrouter not rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Am trying to make my react app into a multiple page app by using Browserrouter library but for some reason my component is not rendering when add the routing functionalities.

Here is my index.js code :

```js
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM  from "react-dom/client"
// Component file
import TodoContainer from "./functionBased/components/TodoContainer";
//Stylesheet
import "./functionBased/App.css"
//React router dom
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


var root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter >
            <TodoContainer />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

When i add routing functionalities my app stop rendering

```js
return (
    <>
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<TodoContainer/>}>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="inner">
                        <Header />
                        <InputTodo addTodoProps={addTodoItem}/>
                        <TodosList 
                            todos={todos} 
                            handleChangeProps={handleChange}
                            deleteTodoProps={delTodo}
                            setUpdate={setUpdate}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />}/>
            <Route path="*" element={<NotMatch />}/>
        </Routes>
    </>
```

Comment: Please update your post to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a formatted and readable *code snippet* instead of images. Images are searchable or copy/pasteable, are less accessible, and can be more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by restructuring my code to make all the routing functionalities in the index.js file as such.

```
var root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<TodoContainer />}/>
            <Route path="about*" element={<About/>}/>
            <Route path="*" element={<NotMatch/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
   </React.StrictMode>
);
```